# CORS error working only for one controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, cors, asp.net-core-mvc

I am working on a dotnet core web api.

My API is hosted on localhost:44366
and My client side application is hosted at http://127.0.0.1:5501/ (using vs code live server)

I am making two POST request using a submit button 
Previously I faced the following issue when I was making **one** POST request:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://localhost:44366/api/surveycreatoroptions' from origin 
'http://127.0.0.1:5501' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is 
present on the requested resource.
```

I have tried the [EnableCors("AllowMyOrigin")] method on both the controllers.

It works the for the first request but not for the second request (giving the same error)

This is what I have used for Enabling CORS

```
 services.AddCors(options =>
            {
            options.AddPolicy("AllowMyOrigin",
             builder => builder.WithOrigins("http://127.0.0.1:5501").AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader())
             ;
            });

        }
```

How can I make it work for both the requests.

Comment: Can you show your code in Configure and ConfigureServices() in Startup.cs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I encountered your problem. For solve this firstly add this code to startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
     services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("MyPolicy", builder =>
     {
      builder.AllowAnyMethod()
             .AllowAnyHeader()
             .AllowAnyOrigin()
             .AllowCredentials();
        }));
        services.Configure<MvcOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.Filters.Add(new CorsAuthorizationFilterFactory("MyPolicy"));
        });
  }}

 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, DiagnosticListener diagnosticListenerSource, DiagnosticObserver diagnosticObserver)
 {
        app.UseCors("MyPolicy");
 }
```

Then "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" should be added to the api send request header.

Typescript example:

```
fetch(window.appSettings.API_URL + path, {
        redirect: 'follow',
        method,
        body: data === null ? null : JSON.stringify(data),
        headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            Authorization: 'Bearer ' + bToken,
        },
    });
```

You can change origin if you want for security

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to see if it work for you

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
      services.AddCors();
      services.AddMvc();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    app.UseCors(
        options => options.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader()
    );

    app.UseMvc();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code in ConfigureServices method

```
services.AddCors(options =>
{
            options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
            builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                                .AllowAnyMethod()
                                .AllowAnyHeader()
                                .AllowCredentials());
});
```

and in Configure method use

```
app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
```